# Manipulate initial conditions of a DE

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, manipulate, simulation

I have a differential equation that I want to solve numerically,
$$y''(t)+3H(t)y'(t)+m^2y(t)=0, \quad H(t)^2=\frac{1}{6M_p^2}(y'(t)^2+m^2y(t)^2)$$
$$N=\int H(t)dt$$
I want to plot $y'(t)$ vs $N$ but I want to manipulate the initial conditions of the DE above.

(Note that I rescaled the DE and let $dy=y'$)

```
Mp = 2.4353*10^18 ;(* Reduced Planck mass = 2.4353*10^18 GeV *)
m = 1.8*10^13 ;(* Inflaton mass = 1.8*10^13 GeV *)
Rm = (1.8*10^13)/(2.4353*10^18); (* Rescaled inflaton mass *)
tfin = 10^7; 
sol = DSolve[{dy'[t] + 3 H[t] dy[t] + Rm^2 y[t] == 0, y[0] == -a, 
dy[0] == b, y'[t] == dy[t], H[t] == Sqrt[(dy[t]^2 + Rm^2 y[t]^2)/6]}, {y,dy,H}, {t, 0, tfin}];
phi = First[y /. sol];
dphi[x_, a_, b_] = First[dy /. sol];
Hubble = First[H /. sol];
N1x[x_] = Integrate[Hubble[t1], {t1, 0, x}];
Manipulate[ParametricPlot[{N1x[x], dphi[x, a, b]}, {x, 0, tfin}],{a, 0, 30}, {b, 0, 0.009}]
```

Based on what I have written,there are some errors that arose, i.e. the initial condition a and b is not a number or a rectangular array of numbers, and some other problems. Can anyone comment on how to modify this?

Comment: In your text description you use the variable "fi" in the `H` defnition, while your code contains `y[t]` at the same place. This is misleading. Could you please somehow remove uncertainty?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Sorry, I was thinking of something else while typing, I edited the post.

Comment: OK, now it is better. What I see further is that you did not finish writing the `Manipulate` statement. It has the opening bracket and has no closing one along with the parameters which you plan to manipulate. Second, the probable reason for the warning is that your boundary conditions are fixed to `-a` and `b`, and this is fed to the `NDSolve` statement. This is an error: `NDSolve` only understands numerical values of all parameters used.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch I've changed to DSolve and made sure the brackets are complete, but there is still an error.

Comment: `MaxStepFraction` and `MaxSteps` are not options for `DSolve`, `PlotLabels` is not an option for `Manipulate`.

Comment: @xzczd I have edited the post but aside from that are there any mistakes in the flow of the code?

Comment: Apparently `DSolve` can't solve this equation set, try `ParametricNDSolve` instead. (Of course other parts of the code needs to be modified accordingly. )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find it better not to solve for the three variables y,dy and H, but solve only for y with a,b as parameters. Like that:

```
    In[99]:= sol[a_, b_] := 
 NDSolve[{y''[t] + 3 Sqrt[(y'[t]^2 + Rm^2 y[t]^2)/6] y'[t] + 
 Rm^2 y[t] == 0, y[0] == -a, y'[0] == b}, y, {t, 0, tfin}]
```

You get an interpolatingFunction

```
  In[100]:= sol[1, 1/1000]

   (*  y->InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 1.*10^7}}, <>]}}   *)
```

Look at y[t],y'[t] and your H[t]

```
   Manipulate[
   Plot[Evaluate[y[t] /. First@sol[a, b]], {t, 0, 10^7}, 
   PlotRange -> All], {{a, 1}, 0, 30}, {{b, 1/1000}, 0, 9/1000}]

   Manipulate[
   Plot[Evaluate[y'[t] /. First@sol[a, b]], {t, 0, 10^7}], {{a, 1}, 0, 
   30}, {{b, 1/1000}, 0, 9/1000}]

  Manipulate[
   Plot[Evaluate[
   Sqrt[(y'[t]^2 + Rm^2 y[t]^2)/6] /. First@sol[a, b]], {t, 0, 
   10^7}], {{a, 1}, 0, 30}, {{b, 1/1000}, 0, 9/1000}]
```

Straightforward would be to integrate N and plot it as follows:

```
  Plot[NIntegrate[
   Evaluate[
   Sqrt[(y'[t]^2 + Rm^2 y[t]^2)/6] /. First@sol[1, 1/1000]], {t, 0, 
    x}], {x, 0, 10^7}] // Timing
```

But this takes a lot of time, since the integration has to be done very often.
It is faster, to create an interpolationFunction of the H-integral to get N as here:

```
     ndsol[a_, b_] := 
     NDSolve[{D[N1x[z], z] == 
     Evaluate[Sqrt[(y'[z]^2 + Rm^2 y[z]^2)/6] /. First@sol[a, b]], 
     N1x[0] == 0}, N1x, {z, 0, tfin}]
```

Plotting shows you, it yields the same result, but much faster

```
    Plot[Evaluate[N1x[x] /. First@ndsol[1, 1/1000]], {x, 0, 
     10^7}] // Timing
```

This manipulates your N[t]

```
    Manipulate[
    Plot[Evaluate[N1x[x] /. First@ndsol[a, b]], {x, 0, 10^7}], {{a, 1}, 
    0, 30}, {{b, 1/1000}, 0, 9/1000}]
```

and this gives the desired ParametricPlot with Manipulation

```
  Manipulate[
   ParametricPlot[
  Evaluate[{N1x[x] /. First@ndsol[a, b], 
   y'[x] /. First@sol[a, b]}], {x, 0, tfin}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {-1 10^-4, 10^-4}}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1], {{a, 1}, 0, 30}, {{b, 1/1000}, 0, 0.009}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Your code is very self explanatory and clear.